# Is it ok to forcemerge with only_expunge_deletes on a read-write index?

Tags: elasticsearch

According to [force merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/indices-forcemerge.html) documentation:

> Force merge should only be called against read-only indices. Running force merge against a read-write index can cause very large segments to be produced (>5Gb per segment), and the merge policy will never consider it for merging again until it mostly consists of deleted docs. This can cause very large segments to remain in the shards.

However, I'm unsure whether it's ok or not to run `forcemerge` with `only_expunge_deletes` on a read-write index. Does the risk of producing very large segments still exist with `only_expunge_deletes` option? If so, how does ES reclaim space usually, when `forcemerge` isn't called manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the quoted documentation, forcemerge should only really be called on read-only indices.

To answer your question, [ES constantly merges segments](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/index-modules-merge.html) in the background and removes deleted documents in the process, so you should never have to worry about this.

You can visualize how that happens in [this great video](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's insightful. I'll definitely watch the video. About ES constantly merging segment, I had a production cluster that switched to yellow status after updating a lot of documents. The cluster was lacking free storage space because old documents weren't expunged (I mean NONE of the documents, even though expunge threshold was by far exceeded). I ran `forcemerge` with `only_expunge_deletes` (indices were read-only anyways due to the cluster status) which luckily did solve the issue. If ES constantly merges segments, space should have been reclaimed sooner isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should have. However, merging also needs free space (potentially twice as much as the used space and sometimes even more), so if you're running out of space, background merging might not happen automatically anymore.