# Delete Data from Elasticsearch Maxed out index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an single Elasticsearch index which has maximum number of documents. i want to delete some data from this index. i have tried running a delete_by_query but it fails. any sugestions for this, which i would able to keep the index and its data and also delete some old data from the same index ?

This is the request i was running.

```
curl -X GET "1localhost:9200/produdtion-index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            { "range": { "submitDate": { "lte": "20200421" } } }   
                        ]
                    }
                }
}
'
```

Comment: What error do you get? Something like "maximum documents per shard reached"?

Comment: when i execute the curl request, terminal shows 'empty response form server' and  Elasticsearch background process is killed. when check the server, bellow error is shown 
[2020-07-24T18:57:08,983][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elastic.servername.xy] fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[elastic.servername.xy][write][T#1]], exiting
java.lang.AssertionError: delete operation should never fail at document level
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.deleteInLucene(InternalEngine.java:1416) ~[elasticsearch-7.3.0.jar:7.3.0]

Comment: When the index was maxed out, i got the error you mentioned. therefore, i moved to daily indexing system. but still due to lack of storage issue, i need to delete some old data from the index. is there a way to permanently delete some documents ? i have tried to get document id and delete it but that didn't worked either.

Comment: If you're missing storage space, it's very hard to get around those issues. You should plan your storage space according to your needs **before** indexing your data. Now, you should increase your storage space if you want to go forward

Comment: Thanks for the tip. it is very hard to increase the storage. anyway, is there a way to delete some documents by hand with doc id ? isn't that solve the problem ?  at least physically in the actual server without any curl requests  or using kibana ?

Comment: Deleting documents doesn't reclaim the space immediately, that just marks the document deleted in the underlying segment files, so that wouldn't solve your issue in the short term. What you can try to do is to [forcemerge the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55904015/4604579), but if you're missing space, it might not work out as the process will require additional space to rewrite the segments without the deleted documents.

Comment: After i call the forcemerge API , i get below result. can you please be kind enough to explain the underline meaning ? {
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}

Comment: it just means that the forcemerge call ran successfully, not much more. Do you see some reclaimed space?

Comment: Only 1GB has been reclaimed as far as i can see. is there more i can do ?

Comment: As I said, calling forcemerge is bandaid, you need to provision enough disk space prior to indexing data. Now your best option is to increase disk space (storage is cheap)

Comment: Thank you very much @Val .  You have bean great help. i have learned my lesson on  taking short paths. :)

Comment: Dear Val, Hope you can help me. I have Tried the Elasticsearch reindex api with a query and new index document count is increasing. I am using an query inside the reindex request and getting all the latest data to new index. My question is, if i delete the old index and keep the new index(re-indexed one),  will my data be safe  in the newly created re-indexed index ?

Answer (score 1):

Try index life cycle managementhttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html
You can split the index based on the number of documents and then delete them

Comment: Thank You mate. not the solution for my problem but it helped me to find the re-index api.